# Is it possible to Wake on LAN without being able to connect to ones router and make changes there?

Tags: router, wake-on-lan

I have the problem that I can't connect to my router, becuase that's just how my provider works. Is it possible to Wake on LAN without being able to connect to the router to make changes? Thanks

Comment: If you have an always-on host inside your network that you can connect to from the outside, you can use it as a kind of WoL gateway/relay/proxy/whatever-you-want-to-call-it to send WoL magic packets to other devices. Is that a possibility for you?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you want to wake the device are you inside or outside of your LAN?  Personally I've never found WOL to be sufficiently reliable to count on. its alright in best-effort-is-ok scenarios, but for anything critical, you want to just disable sleep.